# JQuery cookie expiration detection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery $.cookie to save some data in my app and was wondering if there is a way to detect if the $.cookie has already expired or not?

I know I can check the content by reading the cookie, but how can I know if the cookie already expired or not? Thanks

Comment: If it expired, it's no longer there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cookie has already expired, `$.cookie('cookieName')` will return undefined:

```
if(typeof $.cookie('cookieName') === 'undefined'){

    // 'cookieName' expired (or never existed)
}
```

Hope this helps!